# Missing wlan0 interface for iwl3945

Tags: linux, debian, wifi

I am trying to diagnose an issue I can see on my [LibreELEC.tv 9.0 Alpha 006](https://libreelec.tv/2018/10/libreelec-leia-v8-90-006-alpha/) installation.

If I run a live system, and go to the console (CTRL+ALT+F3), here is what dmesg reveals:

```
$ dmesg | grep 3945
[    7.454039] iwl3945: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG/BG Network Connection driver for Linux, in-tree:s
[    7.454043] iwl3945: Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation
[    7.454045] iwl3945: hw_scan is disabled
[    7.454178] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    7.508456] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 23 802.11a channels
[    7.508461] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: Detected Intel Wireless WiFi Link 3945ABG
[    7.509635] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-3945-rs'
[    7.532150] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: loaded firmware version 15.32.2.9
```

Now if I install a debian (testing) on this system (I did not change anything in the BIOS in the meantime). Here is what I see:

```
$ dmesg | grep 3945
[    8.717721] iwl3945: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG/BG Network Connection driver for Linux, in-tree:s
[    8.717724] iwl3945: Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation
[    8.717810] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    8.771950] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 23 802.11a channels
[    8.771954] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0: Detected Intel Wireless WiFi Link 3945ABG
[    8.958232] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-3945-rs'
[    9.756622] iwl3945 0000:0c:00.0 wlp12s0: renamed from wlan0
```

So the above demonstrate that my card works, it's only there as reference, since my goal is to make it work on LibreELEC.tv installation.

I have been starring at the dmesg output for a while now, but I cannot make sense of the black magic missing during LibreELEC.tv startup. What could be missing that the behavior of the iwl3945 driver is different from a LibreELEC.tv installation compared to a default Debian (testing) installation ?

In the end I'd like to see the wlan0 interface be listed in the output of ifconfig. Currently I only see:

```
# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:8B:B8:08:CD  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Comment: Your interface name is **wlp12s0**, not **wlan0**.

Comment: @igor-sircer you understand that you are talking about the Debian installation and not LibreELEC.tv installation ?

Comment: It wasn't at all clear what you were asking. Your question's much better now. What does `iwconfig` report?

Comment: @roaima there is not such tool as `iwconfig` on LibreELEC.tv installation (connman).